# Problems about Rails on Run Rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Have a problem when I run `rails s`. I cannot see anything on my browser.

I am using localhost 3000 and when I look in the browser nothing shows.

```
    C:\Sites\Zoom>rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Russell's Teapot
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-02 21:33:48 +0300
(1.0ms) SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by StaticPagesController#root as HTML
Rendering static_pages/root.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered static_pages/root.html.erb within layouts/application (9.0ms)
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-02 21:33:52 +0300
Processing by StaticPagesController#root as HTML
Rendering static_pages/root.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered static_pages/root.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14958ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

RuntimeError - can't add a new key into hash during iteration:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/set.rb:153:in `replace'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/set.rb:360:in `collect!'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:85:in `asset_from_cache'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:57:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:311:in `block in fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:307:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:200:in `dfs'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'

sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
sprockets (3.7.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:92:in `[]'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:355:in `find_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:347:in `find_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:229:in `block in lookup_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `block in resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:241:in `resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:228:in `lookup_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:141:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:140:in `javascript_include_tag'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:26:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___677905375_75171192'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:352:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:64:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:50:in `render_template'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:24:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:29:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:33:in `default_render'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionview (5.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
better_errors (2.3.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
better_errors (2.3.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
better_errors (2.3.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
rack-livereload (0.3.16) lib/rack/livereload.rb:23:in `_call'
rack-livereload (0.3.16) lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:3enter code here01:in `block in run'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'

Completed 200 OK in 11953ms (Views: 11941.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this a new, or a known working ruby/rails installation? Has this application worked previously?

Comment: https://github.com/michaelzhu1/Zoomm/

Comment: I read somewhere you could try changing line 26 in your application.html.erb  to `javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'`

Comment: It's probably the same issue discussed here: https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/242